# VB9 New thread with multiple parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, lambda

I'm trying to create a new thread and send multiple parameters as well as a delegate to report back.

In VB8 I always hate to do this because it requires either introducing a new class/structure or a delegate.

Is there any better way to do this in VB9 ?

I'm looking for a solution something like this :

```
   Dim Th As New Thread(AddressOf DoStuff)
   Th.Start(param1, param2, AddressOf ReportStatus)
```

I'm not good with LINQ and Lambda, so I'm hopping that someone will show me some cool trick to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* pass an anonymous function to the thread constructor.

```
Dim Th = New Thread(Sub() DoStuff(param1, param2, AddressOf ReportStatus))
```

but unfortunately there are no anonymous subs in VB9 (they will be in VB10 - In C# this should already work).

Comment: OK, I thought it was possible in VB9, shame on MS

Comment: Shame on MS?  It's people like you that give MS a bad name.  Microsoft has consistantly improved the VB and C# languages with every single release.  Shame on YOU for not giving credit where credit is deserved.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Nothing new in VB9.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're already familiar with this, but depending on your application, using ThreadPool can be useful and easy. I don't know much about sending parameters with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, but [this](http://thevalerios.net/matt/2008/05/use-threadpoolqueueuserworkitem-with-anonymous-types/) page seems to give a good tutorial involving lambda expressions and anonymous types. It's in C# but I'm sure it would translate to VB.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to something similar but that page is in C# (I can read C# and convert except Linq and lambad :) ). Also I'm not sure how much of it can be applied to VB.NET